# Add page title below image in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, pdfmake

I have added an image to the pdf document as per the documentation at https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfImage.html
This displays the image below the page title. However, I want the image on top of the title. How can I change the ordering of these two elements?

Below is the javascript code I am using:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "pageLength": 50,
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel',
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
                    image: 'data:image/png;base64,==image-text-here==',
                    margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                    alignment: 'center',
                    width: 250,
                    height: 100
                } );
            }
        }, 'print'
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Are you using any CSS? If yes, please share it

Comment: @Vortex No. But I am using the bootstrap 4 theme for datatables

Comment: try recreating your scenario using jsbin, since pdf output shown in website you mentioned, image is at top of the table.

Comment: I have a page title and an image both above the table, however, I want the image to be on top of the page in this order image->page title->table. Right now it is page title->image->table